# Using the derived table in the JOIN statement

Tags: php, mysql, join, derived-table

I have a database query in PHP similar to:

```
SELECT * FROM ($myQuery) AS myDerivedTable
JOIN ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myDerivedTable WHERE criteriaA ) AS A
JOIN ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myDerivedTable WHERE criteriaB ) AS B
JOIN ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myDerivedTable WHERE criteriaC ) AS C
...
```

For now, suppose the `$myQuery` contains the following:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY dateOfSubmition DESC
```

I just want to use the derived table (`myDerivedTable`) again and again, instead of calculating it every time! But mySQL reports an error:

> `#1146 - Table 'myDB.myDerivedTable' doesn't exist`

Of course it doesn't exist! By `myDerivedTable`, I didn't meant to mention an existent table in the database, but just a reference to the already calculated table!!

How may I achieve the desired behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another way using conditional aggregation to get counts for different criteria

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN criteriaA THEN 1 END) AS A
    COUNT(CASE WHEN criteriaB THEN 1 END) AS B
    COUNT(CASE WHEN criteriaC THEN 1 END) AS C
FROM ($myQuery) AS myDerivedTable
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply :) But now mySQL says `#1137 - Can't reopen table: 'myTempTable' `, since the [documentations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/temporary-table-problems.html) say _"You cannot refer to a `TEMPORARY` table more than once in the same query,"_ Is there another workaround?

Comment: I really appreciate your attention, you're a hero :) and yes, for this very specific case, I actually was after some _"`COUNT`"s!_ and since your new approach solves my problem and that I think my methodology to achieve the behavior is probably far off-roads!! I accept your post as an answer despite I think this is not the _ultimate_ solution for the original post!

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below, It may help you.

http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1570/html/sqlug/sqlug432.htm